# Force.com IDE, Cannot get global quick action

Tags: force.com, metadata

I added the New Task Quick action to a custom object and pulled it into Eclipse with force.com IDE with no problem. Using force.com IDE I retrieved all quickActions and got the Object.New_Task.quickAction file. I then added the New Event quick action to the page layout in the same manner:[image]

But I cannot see it in the available meta data components(Looking for Practice_Management_Guide__c.New_Event):[image]

... Even though, the New Event quick actions are shown on the the layout(I added both):

```
<platformActionListItems>
    <actionName>NewEventGlobal</actionName>
    <actionType>QuickAction</actionType>
    <sortOrder>19</sortOrder>
</platformActionListItems>
<platformActionListItems>
    <actionName>NewEvent</actionName>
    <actionType>QuickAction</actionType>
    <sortOrder>20</sortOrder>
</platformActionListItems>
```

Comment: Have you tried reconnecting to your org?

Comment: No why would I have to do that ?

Comment: To make sure that your local copy fetches the latest details from server.

Comment: Alright I'll try that

Comment: I've refreshed from server a couple times

Comment: Did you try the refresh button on the upper-right corner (the two arrows pointing at each other)? That tends to fix these kinds of problems.

Comment: Yeah I tried that